# int to bufferbyte

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have the following:

```
byte[] l = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putInt(N).array();
```

but it puts the bytes at the beggining of the array and not to the end of it
how do i put it to the end?
I've tried the following too:

```
byte[] l = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putInt(15 - (int)Math.ceil((Math.log(N)/Math.log(2))/8), N * 8).array();
```

but seems to work with some numbers, but in others get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsIndexException (they are lower than 2<sup>16</sup>)

Comment: `ByteBuffer.putInt` will always write exactly four bytes.  Don't bother with the logarithm crap.

Comment: yep, seems that it is limited to 4 bytes... seems that ill have to do a for manually to insert them, unless there is any other way....

Answer (score 1):

> it puts the bytes at the beggining of the array and not to the end of it how do i put it to the end? I've tried the following too:

Here's where the problem is. Although you call `ByteBuffer.allocate(16)`, this just sets the capacity to 16, your buffer is still empty. So when you try to add something at index 15, there's nothing there and you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because the buffer's size is still 0 and you are accessing index 15. You can't write to the end of the buffer until it's filled up to that index.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier ByteBuffer.putInt will always write 4 bytes.  So how about

```
byte[] l = ByteBuffer.allocate(12).putInt(N).array();
```

The following program shows the difference:

```
  int N = 99;

  byte[] l = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putInt(N).array();
  System.out.println("N at start: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(l));

  l = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putInt(12,N).array();
  System.out.println("N at end:   " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(l));
```

which prints out the following:

```
N at start: 00000063000000000000000000000000 
N at end:   00000000000000000000000000000063
```

Comment: so i cant use for N > 2^(8*4)?